# Difference between class_weight and loss_weights in Keras

Tags: classification, keras

Keras has parameters `class_weight` used in `fit()` function and `loss_weights` used in `compile()` function. From the explanation([Docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)) and what I understand, it seems that both are identical, as they are used to indicate the importance of each class. However, what is the difference between the two? And what are the scenarios in which they can be appropriately used?

Answer (score 6):

From Keras Team at [GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10507):

> **loss_weights** parameter on compile is used to define how much each of
>   your model output loss contributes to the final loss value ie. it
>   weighs the model output losses. You could have a model with 2 outputs
>   where one is the primary output and the other auxiliary. eg. 1. *
>   primary + 0.3 * auxiliary. The default values for loss weights is 1.
>
> **class_weight** parameter on fit is used to weigh the importance of each
>   sample based on the class they belong to, during training. This is
>   typically used when you have an uneven distribution of samples per
>   class.

Comment: loss_weights still not that clear

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it: If you have one loss function this produces one loss output per sample. So if you have multiple loss functions this will generate multiple loss outputs. When using **loss_weights** this will weight the multiple loss function outputs per sample.

For **class_weight** this will look at the class of the true label and multiply its corresponding weight with the loss output.